# Dapper casting issue in stored procedure with conditional select queries

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, dapper

I am faced with casting issue when calling a stored procedure that has two select queries where only one of the query will be executed based on an if else condition. BOTH the select queries have the same values being selected, but in different order. Just to give an idea,

```
IF (some condition)
 SELECT
  t1.Id,
  t1.Title,
  t1.Description
 FROM Table1 t1
ELSE
 SELECT
  t1.Title,
  t1.Id,
  t1.Description
 FROM Table1 t1
```

Scenario:

1. Method that executes this stored procedure is called, condition is satisfied.
2. Expected data is returned.
3. Method that executes this stored procedure is called, condition is not satisfied.
4. Casting error thrown in code.

> Error parsing column 0 (Id=123 - Int64)
> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int64' to type 'System.String'.
> at Deserializec2c12182-6e8d-4a6e-8f54-e60138f070ee(IDataReader )

Changing them to the same selection order will bypass the issue, but can anybody tell if this is some caching issue with Dapper, or anything else?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why not just return the columns in the same order? I am guessing, but under the hood Dapper may be calling [`sp_describe_first_result_set`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and then using the results from that to index into the returned dataset. But `sp_describe_first_result_set` will only describe the first possible result set, not the second.

Comment: @DaleK All very nice, but IMO this might be a bug (don't have a chance to test now). Could make a big difference to procedures where different columns are returned depending on parameters, eg large `max` columns which you want to avoid returning if not necessary

Comment: @Charlieface its a total guess on my part - having never actually used dapper... I'm still an ADO.NET kinda guy lol. I would normally consider it bad practice to return a completely different resultset depending on the parameters though.

Comment: @DaleK Yes I am able to bypass the error by changing it to the same order, but I would really like to see what's happening.

Comment: If you run the SQL Profiler you can see whether `sp_describe_first_result_set ` gets called. If it does thats your answer. If not... its some other reason.

Comment: @DaleK Looks like the mapping code uses the column indexes for reader it has in hand, which is then cached. IMO a bug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Looking at the source code for Dapper](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper/blob/29f3befae244907baf9c2d919db616fa7de99cb1/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs#L3451), it appears that the generated mapping code uses the index to read the data from `DbDataReader`. I would imagine that accessing by index is faster than by name, which is why it is done this way.

[This mapper is cached](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper/blob/29f3befae244907baf9c2d919db616fa7de99cb1/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs#L60) (for performance) and used for identical runs of the same command text, so Dapper expects the columns to be in the same order.

I personally feel that this is a bug, and that the cache logic should take into account the column ordering when checking for an existing mapper. [Feel free to file a bug report.](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper/issues)

---

As mentioned by [@RoarS. in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68148223/dapper-casting-issue-in-stored-procedure-with-conditional-select-queries/68148376?noredirect=1#comment120448286_68148376), a workaround is to switch off caching, by using an explicit `CommandDefinition`

```cs
var cmdDef = new CommandDefinition("select ... blah ...", new { a, b }, commandType: CommandType.Text, flags: CommandFlags.NoCache);
```

This shouldn't be necessary, Dapper should check whether the reader is the same before trying to reuse it.

Comment: How does it generate the mapping codes in the first place though?

Comment: That's in the first link, as well as [here](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper/blob/29f3befae244907baf9c2d919db616fa7de99cb1/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs#L3223) which references it

Comment: I was hoping you might be able to summarise briefly :) I assume you are saying its not using `sp_describe_first_result_set`, but rather converting the named values to indexes on the first run?

Comment: Hence `var cmdDef = new CommandDefinition("select ... blah ...", new { a, b }, commandType: CommandType.Text, flags: CommandFlags.NoCache);` and pass `cmdDef` to query, should make a difference. https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper/issues/1075

Comment: @DaleK I can't say I understand all of the code (it's generating MSIL property accessors on the fly) but it does indeed seem to do that, see [here](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper/blob/29f3befae244907baf9c2d919db616fa7de99cb1/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs#L3230) for where it pulls out the indexes

Answer (score -3):

Seems like the ordering of the columns in the first and second statement is incorrect. So when dapper queries the stored proc by index of the column there is a mismatch in the type of the columns in both statements. In the first statement the datatype of the first column is INT 64 whereas in the second statement it is String. Hence the issue. So the correct SQL Procedure would look like this:

```
IF (some condition)
 SELECT
  t1.Id,
  t1.Title,
  t1.Description
 FROM Table1 t1
ELSE
 SELECT
  t1.Id,
  t1.Title,
  t1.Description
 FROM Table1 t1
```

Comment: Thats not the what the OP is asking. They are aware of that already.

Comment: And I already formatted it for you, correctly using code formatting rather then HTML formatting.

Comment: please clarify properly